# Are joins in redshift fast than unionall? How can I make my queries faster?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a complex query in redshift where I am taking unionAll from three different tables, doing aggregation, listagg to get desired results. I cannot share the query for privacy reasons, is there any way to make my query execution fast? currently it takes about 100-120 seconds to retrieve 0.3mn result rows. I have tried group by in order of sort keys already

Comment: It all depends on your data and your query. The main things that make Redshift go fast are correct use of `DISTKEY` and `SORTKEY` based upon the normal querying pattern.

Comment: can you share a anonomised version of your code at all? if not then you will not be able to get any help here.

Comment: Like @JonScott suggested, can you share an anonymized version of the queries? Join can be quite fast if you use the same DISTKEY for your tables.